# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: n.class

Tags: android, exception, gradle, runtime-error

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "[ MY PACKAGE ]"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


}
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'com.github.deano2390:android-viewbadger:1.0.0'
    compile('com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-compat'
    }
    compile project(':Library_MobilePaymentSDK')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.4.2@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    compile 'rongi.rotate-layout:rotate-layout:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.maksim88:PasswordEditText:v0.9'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.jcmore2.appcrash:appcrash:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.stfalcon:smsverifycatcher:0.2'
    compile 'com.github.javiersantos:BottomDialogs:1.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
    compile files('libs/mpaysdk-sandbox-1.0.28.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
```

this gradle file works in api 21 but when i run on api 19 the following error occured.
the following error occured:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: n.class

plz help me to solve this problem.

Comment: the exception occured after adding  jar file (at last gradle)                                      
                                                                                                   
        compile files('libs/mpaysdk-sandbox-1.0.28.jar')

Comment: You don't require to add this line compile files('libs/mpaysdk-sandbox-1.0.28.jar'), this line compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') will add all .jar

Comment: in your app dir build.gradle file add this  `configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }`

Comment: afaik, there is compatibility error when using support library 24 and google play service. Try change your support library to 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution#1:

In terminal, You can execute the following command in your root project folder:

> ./gradlew clean

## Solution#2:

If you use Android Studio, then you can do it easily, Go to Menu

> Build/Clean Project

It will update old dependencies

## Solution#3:

You can add the following section to your `build.gradle` file:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```